# Bootstrap convert navbar to side bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sidebar

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I want to create a sidebar, like the one that appear in mobile apps where they are hidden initially and appear from left to right on click.

The following html which uses bootstrap, creates a nav bar which on smaller devices changes into a collapsable icon. On clicking the icon the menu appears from top down. Does bootstrap provide feature to change the transition direction? Please help, I am new to css and bootstrap

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
       </button>
    </div>
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Demo</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">City <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pune</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hyderabad</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has built in functionality for sidebar menus.

http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/navigation-sidebar-with-toggle